# Difference between a equation and a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I. Consider V as the plane given by $x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 = 0$ in $R^3$.

II. Is $\vec{x}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ -3 \\ 6\end{pmatrix}$ in the plan V?

This seems like a boring problem. I understand that $\vec{x}$ is in the plane V since $(1)(3) + (3)(-3) + (1)(6)$ indeed equals 0, but I am having trouble conceptually understanding the difference between an equation and vector.

**Questions:**

> A. I might be wrong, but $V$ looks linearly dependent. Is $\vec{x}$ called a plane, because there are two free variables, thus
> $x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 = 0$ spans some 2D plane? If-so, why
> did they say this equation is in $R^3$? Is it not true that dim($V$) = 1?
>
> B. What if someone asked me to get the dot product of V and some vector
> $\vec{b}$? How would that even work? Is that even possible? Clearly I
> would know dot product of $\vec{x}$ and some vector $\vec{b}$
>
> C. If that "= 0" was not there, wouldn't V just be a vector?
>
> D. Can $\vec{x}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ -3 \\ 6\end{pmatrix}$ be
> written as $3x_1 + -3x_2 + 6x_3$?

So A, B, C, and D are questions to demonstrate my confusion. What I really what to know is how an equation and a vector differ **geometrically**, as well as some intuitive written explanation of their difference. A 2D example is acceptable for easier visualization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the plane $V$ is the *set* of all vectors
$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^3$$
such that $x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 = 0$. So, the correct way to write the plane is
$$V = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^3 : x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 = 0 \right\},$$ and, for example,
$$\begin{pmatrix} 3\\-3\\6\end{pmatrix} \in V.$$